# Inserting a file into an array in Meteor using aldeed:autoform, cfs:autoform and the update-pushArray type

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, collectionfs

I'd like to build an array of uploaded files in each document in my collection named Modules.  I'm using the following packages:

- aldeed:autoform
- aldeed:collection2
- cfs:standard-packages
- cfs:gridfs
- cfs:autoform

Collection and Schema (relevant parts):

```
Modules = new Mongo.Collection('modules');
Modules.attachSchema (new SimpleSchema({
    slides: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    'slides.$': {
        type: Object
    },
    'slides.$.fileId': {
        type: String,
        label: "Image File"
    },
    'slides.$.time': {
        type: Number,
        label: "Time in Seconds"
    }
}));

FileStore = new FS.Collection("fileStore", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("fileStore")]
});

FileStore.allow({
    download: function() {
        return true;
    },
    fetch: null
});
```

In the HTML Template:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Modules" scope="slides" id="addSlideForm" type="update-pushArray" doc=this}}
    <fieldset>
        {{> afQuickField name="time" type="number"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="fileId" type="cfs-file" collection="fileStore"}}
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Add Slide</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

When I hit the submit button, an element is pushed into the array as expected. The `time` value is correct, but under `fileId` there is only `dummyId` instead of the expected _id from `fileStore`.

In other parts of the application that do not involve nested arrays, uploading files works as expected.  In other parts of the application that do not involve uploading files, the `update-pushArray` form works as expected.  The complication is with combining the two.

Am I doing this incorrectly?  Or is cfs:autoform just not compatible with the `update-pushArray` form type?

Answer (score 0):

To use CFS your #autoform type must be either "insert" or "method", check cfs documentation for more info.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.